# Use of RSA key Wrapping using MSCAPI

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle, encryption-asymmetric

I am using AES Symmetric encryption of data using BouncyCastle provider, and then wrapping the key using RSA Asymmetric algorithm from Public key obtained from Windows keystore certificate using SunMSCAPI provider. Can anyone please help how to use the SunMSCAPI for RSA wrapping and unwrapping of symmetric keys appropriately with some code snippet?

Answer (score 2):

[sweeping old questions]

You can just use javax.crypto.Cipher.wrap() and unwrap() using the retrieved instances of RSAPublicKey and RSAPrivateKey. For this you may need the unlimited crypto policy files from Sun/Oracle for your JDK/JRE.